# Call jQuery on from apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am writing a small library that will take care of adding and removing events. I am simply attempting to pass the parameters of a method to jQuery `on`.
Is there any reason that I should not be able to do this?

```
# within some object 
...
on: (el, args...) ->
 $(el).on.apply(this, args)
```

The way I am using `this` may not be correct, but I don't believe it is the problem.

Which would then be called like so:

```
SomeObj.on('#hi', 'click'
  -> console.log('clicked element')
)
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: elem.each is not a function`

For some reason this is totally stumping me.

Comment: You've got the wrong `this`. You need the `$(el)`

Comment: @Amit Oh wow that worked!

Comment: @Amit Why exactly?

Comment: No need to create a jQuery object just to get the method. Use `$.fn.on.call($(this), args)`, though I don't know why you need this.

Comment: ...I should note that `$.fn.on` is the same as `$.prototype.on`

Comment: @Johnston I'm certain that `.on` uses `this` at some point. After all, the jQuery object (`$(el)`) contains the elements it's applying event handlers to it. How else would it know what elements to bind to? So by passing `this` you're instead passing `SomeObj` which doesn't contain the elements you're binding to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem *is* the wrong usage of `this`, despite your assumption.

The issue is that when you call a member function ("method"), it usually operates on some object, it's "context". Invoking a function via `apply`, `call` or through `bind` doesn't have the context passed in automatically because that gets lost when you access the properties of the function (`apply` in this case). In order to overcome this, it off required to set the relevant `this` attribute. In your case, this means passing the `$(el)` object to the `apply()` function.